# IOS cannot add poly markers only polylines drawn no markers added

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios, polyline

I am currently developing the module which can show markers and polyline to show the route a robot can go from position A to position B. when it comes to adding the markers and lines by long touch, it shows only GMSPolylines are drawn and added. However, there is no markers added. Would your please tell me is it possible to draw markers and polyliens between respectively ?

The below is my code

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:22.2855200
                                                            longitude:114.1576900
                                                                 zoom:12];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.delegate = self;

    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    // mapView_.delegate = self;
    self.view = mapView_;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.2855200, 114.1576900);
    marker.title = @"My place";
    marker.snippet = @"HK";
    marker.map = mapView_;


}


- (void)addMarkers
{
  //  [mapView_ clear];
    if([array count] > 0){
        GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
        for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
            CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(11.11 , 123.123);
            GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
            marker.position = position;
            marker.title = @"Desitnation";
            NSString *tmpLat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", position.latitude];
            NSString *tmpLong = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", position.longitude];
            marker.snippet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", tmpLat,tmpLong];

            UIColor *color;
            CheckPoints *cp = [array objectAtIndex:i];
            [path addLatitude:cp.getLatitude longitude:cp.getLongitude];
            GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
            polyline.geodesic = YES;
            polyline.strokeWidth = 10.f;
            if (cp.getState ==1) {
                // Green
                color = [UIColor colorWithHue:.2 saturation:1.f brightness:1.f alpha:1.0f];
                polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            } else {
                color = [UIColor colorWithHue:1. saturation:1.f brightness:1.f alpha:1.0f];
                polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
            }
            marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:color];
            marker.map = mapView_;
            polyline.map = mapView_;
        }

    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
//    GMSMarker *marker3 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
//    marker3.position = coordinate;
//    marker3.title = @"Desitnation";
//    NSString *tmpLat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
//    NSString *tmpLong = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];
//    marker3.snippet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", tmpLat,tmpLong];
//    
//    marker3.map = mapView_;


    CheckPoints *myCar=[[CheckPoints alloc] init];
    [myCar setState:0];
    [myCar setLatitude:coordinate.latitude];
    [myCar setLongitude:coordinate.longitude];
    NSString* theTextValue = @"Desitnation";
    [myCar setDesp:theTextValue];

    NSLog( @"%d", myCar.getState );
    NSLog( @"%f", myCar.getLatitude);
    NSLog( @"%f", myCar.getLongitude );
    NSLog( @"%@", myCar.getDesp );

    [array addObject:myCar];
    CheckPoints *lastChk = array.lastObject;
    for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        CheckPoints *current =  [array objectAtIndex:i];
        if(current.getLatitude != lastChk.getLatitude && current.getLongitude != lastChk.getLongitude){
            [current setState:1];
            NSString* previousTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"Checkpoint" ,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
            [current setDesp:previousTitle];
        }
    }
    [self addMarkers];
    [ToastView showToastInParentView:self.view withText:@"What a toast!" withDuaration:5.0];


}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you never use the path point's coordinate but a hardcoded one:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(11.11 , 123.123);
```

**use the path**

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = [path coordinateAtIndex:i];
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are adding the same marker repeatedly...

```
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(11.11 , 123.123);
        GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
```

...hardcoded point.

Answer (score 2):

self.googleMapsView is the google maps view.

Example  : self.getDirections("26.9211992,75.8185761", destination: "26.8472496,75.7691909", waypoints: ["26.8686811,75.7568383"], travelMode: nil, completionHandler: nil)

Example: google direction link
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=26.9211992,75.8185761&destination=26.8472496,75.7691909&waypoints=optimize:true|26.8686811,75.7568383

```
   let baseURLGeocode = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"
let baseURLDirections = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"

var selectedRoute: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>!

var overviewPolyline: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>!

var originCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

var destinationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D!


func getDirections(origin: String!, destination: String!, waypoints: Array<String>!, travelMode: AnyObject!, completionHandler: ((status: String, success: Bool) -> Void)?) {
    if let originLocation = origin {
        if let destinationLocation = destination {
            var directionsURLString = baseURLDirections + "origin=" + originLocation + "&destination=" + destinationLocation
            if let routeWaypoints = waypoints {
                directionsURLString += "&waypoints=optimize:true"

                for waypoint in routeWaypoints {
                    directionsURLString += "|" + waypoint
                }
            }
            print(directionsURLString)
            directionsURLString = directionsURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let directionsURL = NSURL(string: directionsURLString)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                let directionsData = NSData(contentsOfURL: directionsURL!)
                do{
                    let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(directionsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                    let status = dictionary["status"] as! String

                    if status == "OK" {
                        self.selectedRoute = (dictionary["routes"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>)[0]
                        self.overviewPolyline = self.selectedRoute["overview_polyline"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                        let legs = self.selectedRoute["legs"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>

                        let startLocationDictionary = legs[0]["start_location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                        self.originCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(startLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, startLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

                        let endLocationDictionary = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                        self.destinationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(endLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, endLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

                        let originAddress = legs[0]["start_address"] as! String
                        let destinationAddress = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_address"] as! String

                        let originMarker = GMSMarker(position: self.originCoordinate)
                        originMarker.map = self.googleMapsView
                        originMarker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImageWithColor(UIColor.greenColor())
                        originMarker.title = originAddress

                        let destinationMarker = GMSMarker(position: self.destinationCoordinate)
                        destinationMarker.map = self.googleMapsView
                        destinationMarker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImageWithColor(UIColor.redColor())
                        destinationMarker.title = destinationAddress

                        if waypoints != nil && waypoints.count > 0 {
                            for waypoint in waypoints {
                                let lat: Double = (waypoint.componentsSeparatedByString(",")[0] as NSString).doubleValue
                                let lng: Double = (waypoint.componentsSeparatedByString(",")[1] as NSString).doubleValue

                                let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng))
                                marker.map = self.googleMapsView
                                marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImageWithColor(UIColor.purpleColor())

                            }
                        }

                        let route = self.overviewPolyline["points"] as! String

                        let path: GMSPath = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: route)!
                        let routePolyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
                        routePolyline.map = self.googleMapsView
                    }
                    else {
                        print("status")
                        //completionHandler(status: status, success: false)
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("catch")

                   // completionHandler(status: "", success: false)
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            print("Destination is nil.")
            //completionHandler(status: "Destination is nil.", success: false)
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Origin is nil")
        //completionHandler(status: "Origin is nil", success: false)
    }
}
```